# Outlook Script: Forward e-mail without the attachment

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm looking for a script to forward all incoming emails to a distribution group, but without the attachment. I need the attachment to remain on the original e-mail so it can't just be deleted. I'm using Microsoft Outlook 2010.

So just for the sake of clarity: An e-mail comes in with something attached. I want to forward this e-mail minus the attachment to a different address, while keeping the original intact.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can offer some assistance with this.

Edit: This process needs to happen automatically on every e-mail that comes in to this address.

Comment: Will this be happening automatically?  Or will it happen from, e.g., a button on the ribbon?

Comment: It needs to happen automatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602116/trigger-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following code into your `ThisOutlookSession` module:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMailEx(ByVal EntryIDCollection As String)
    Dim varEntryID As Variant

    For Each varEntryID In Split(EntryIDCollection, ",")
        Dim objOriginalItem As MailItem
        Set objOriginalItem = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetItemFromID(varEntryID)
        Dim objForwardedItem As MailItem
        Set objForwardedItem = objOriginalItem.Forward

        Do Until objForwardedItem.Attachments.Count = 0
            objForwardedItem.Attachments.Remove (1)
        Loop

        objForwardedItem.To = "toemailaddress@domain.com"
        objForwardedItem.Send
    Next
End Sub
```

This module can be accessed in the VBA IDE (Alt + F11) in the Project Explorer: `Project > Microsoft Outlook Objects > ThisOutlookSession`

Comment: Sorry, I should have included this in the original question so I'll edit it.. but it needs to happen automatically on every e-mail that comes in.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how do I make this run on incoming messages?

Comment: It will run whenever a new message arrives because it's inside the `Application_NewMailEx` event handler.  This is one of the built-in event handlers you can use in Outlook VBA from inside the `ThisOutlookSession` module.

Comment: It's not working. I put the code into my ThisOutlookSession module, but when an e-mail comes in nothing happens. I also made sure to change the forward to email address.

Comment: Do any macros work?  Is Outlook set to trust macros?  Check under Outlook options "Trust Center" page > "Trust Center Settings" button > "Macro Settings" page -- make sure "Enable All Macros" is selected.  Also, you can run a simple test by creating a "Sub Test()" with just a Msgbox("testing") inside the sub body, then place the cursor inside the body and hit F5.  If you see the dialog, macros are working.

Comment: You were correct, I had macros disabled. Thanks for your help!